# Upgrading from 8.9.19 to 9 fails because of root composer.json require (^8.8.0)

Tags: updating, composer

My upgrade is failing. I am at 8.9.19 and I used `upgrade-status` to make sure all my modules are compatible with next major core version. I am following instructions at https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later

When I get to step 3, running `composer update`, I'm getting a slew of problems of the form

```
- drupal/core-recommended 9.0.0 requires drupal/core 9.0.0 -> found drupal/core[9.0.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^8.9.19)
```

mentioning all 9.x versions. I can post my entire composer.json if that will help, but I think these are the relevant lines:

```
        "drupal/core": "^8.9.19",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
...
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^9"
    },
```

I had originally created the project with

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev www --stability dev --no-interaction
```

Any suggestions, or pointers to a different tutorial on upgrading, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to remove the line `"drupal/core": "^8.9.19",` from your composer.json. Maybe also refer to https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer for updating drupal using composer, which highlights the difference between using `drupal/core` and `drupal/core-recommended`. The latter is the, well, recommended way at the moment.

Comment: Yes. There is no need for that when you have core-recommended.

Comment: Thanks - I removed "drupal/core": "^8.9.19" and the previous errors went away, but I don't know what to make of these new ones; they are all similar to the last one:     `- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.3.10 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.x-dev]`

Comment: symfony/var-dumper is not in my composer.json -- aha, I found it in vendor/symfony/var-dumper/composer.json -- what is the correct way to remove this redpendency? Blow away the whole directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a var-dumper conflict?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308077/how-do-i-fix-a-var-dumper-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had to remove the `drupal/core` package from the `composer.json` and update the Devel module to fix a conflict with `symfony/var-dumper`.