# How do I fix a var-dumper conflict?

Tags: 9, upgrading

My upgrade is failing. I am at 8.9.19 and I used upgrade-status to make sure all my modules are compatible with next major core version. I am following instructions at https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later

When I get to step 3, running composer update, I get these problems:

```
- Root composer.json requires drupal/devel ^2.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/devel[2.1.0, 2.x-dev (alias of dev-2.x)].
- drupal/core-recommended 9.1.0-alpha1 requires symfony/var-dumper v5.1.7 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.1.7].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.7 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended 9.2.0-alpha1 requires symfony/var-dumper v5.2.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.2.6].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.2.6 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended 9.3.0-alpha1 requires symfony/var-dumper v5.3.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.3.8].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.3.8 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended[9.2.0-beta1, ..., 9.2.0-beta2] require symfony/var-dumper v5.2.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.2.8].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.2.8 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended 9.2.0-beta3 requires symfony/var-dumper v5.3.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.3.0-RC1].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.3.0-RC1 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended[9.0.0-beta3, ..., 9.0.0-rc1] require symfony/var-dumper v5.0.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.0.8].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.0.8 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended[9.0.0, ..., 9.0.12] require symfony/var-dumper v5.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.1.0].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended[9.1.0-beta1, ..., 9.1.7] require symfony/var-dumper v5.1.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.1.8].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.8 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended[9.0.13, ..., 9.1.x-dev] require symfony/var-dumper v5.1.11 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.1.11].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.11 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended[9.2.0-rc1, ..., 9.2.x-dev] require symfony/var-dumper v5.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.3.0].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
- drupal/core-recommended 9.0.0-alpha1 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.7.0].
- drupal/core-recommended[9.0.0-alpha2, ..., 9.0.0-beta2] require composer/installers v1.8.0 -> satisfiable by composer/installers[v1.8.0].
- composer/installers[v1.7.0, ..., v1.8.0] require composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
- drupal/core-recommended[9.3.x-dev, ..., 9.4.x-dev] require symfony/var-dumper v5.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.3.10].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.3.10 (conflict analysis result)
- Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.x-dev].
```

I don't understand the issues or what to do. var-dumper is not in my `composer.json`, but I do see it in k

I have also tried running update with -W, no change. How do I tell what version is being used? Do I need to install or delete something? Running symfony/var-dumper shows this:

```
drupal/devel           2.1.0    requires   symfony/var-dumper (~2.7|^3|^4)           
psy/psysh              v0.10.9  requires   symfony/var-dumper (~5.0|~4.0|~3.0|~2.7)  
symfony/error-handler  v4.4.30  requires   symfony/var-dumper (^4.4|^5.0)            
symfony/http-kernel    v3.4.49  conflicts  symfony/var-dumper (<3.3)
```

Here is my complete `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.8",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "drupal/addanother": "^1.0",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.3",
        "drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar": "^1.11",
        "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.5",
        "drupal/advagg": "^4.1",
        "drupal/backup_migrate": "^5.0@RC",
        "drupal/bamboo_twig": "^5.0-alpha1",
        "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^5.0",
        "drupal/block_field": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/blog": "^3.0",
        "drupal/classy_paragraphs": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/coffee": "^1.0",
        "drupal/config_delete": "^1.17",
        "drupal/config_inspector": "^1.1",
        "drupal/config_update": "^1.7",
        "drupal/console": "~1.0",
        "drupal/contentimport": "^9.3",
        "drupal/context": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
        "drupal/createandcontinue": "^1.2",
        "drupal/cshs": "^2.3",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.4",
        "drupal/d8w3css": "^1.17",
        "drupal/devel": "^2.1",
        "drupal/disable_messages": "^2.0",
        "drupal/draggable_dashboard": "^1.4",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.7",
        "drupal/editablefields": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/email_registration": "^1.1",
        "drupal/empty_page": "^3.0",
        "drupal/entity": "^1.1",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.5",
        "drupal/entity_print": "^2.2",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.8",
        "drupal/entity_usage": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/examples": "^3.0",
        "drupal/extlink": "^1.5",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.1",
        "drupal/graphql": "^3.0",
        "drupal/graphql_core": "^3.0",
        "drupal/homebox": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/htmlmail": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/image_effects": "^3.0",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/jquery_ui": "^1.4",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^1.1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_datepicker": "^1.1",
        "drupal/libraries": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/link_attributes": "^1.11",
        "drupal/mailcontrol": "^1.2",
        "drupal/maillog": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.3",
        "drupal/menu_per_role": "^1.3",
        "drupal/metatag_head_title": "^1.1",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/multiple_registration": "^2.92",
        "drupal/openapi": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/openapi_ui": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.12",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8",
        "drupal/profile": "^1.1",
        "drupal/publication_date": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/publishcontent": "^1.3",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.6",
        "drupal/registration_types": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/rename_admin_paths": "^2.0",
        "drupal/responsive_menu": "4.4.1",
        "drupal/save_edit": "^1.3",
        "drupal/sendgrid_integration": "^1.7",
        "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^3.10",
        "drupal/simplelogin": "^6.0",
        "drupal/system_stream_wrapper": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/tablesorter": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/taxonomy_manager": "^2.0",
        "drupal/term_csv_export_import": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/token": "^1.7",
        "drupal/twig_debugger": "^1.1",
        "drupal/twig_field_value": "^2.0",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.6",
        "drupal/twigsuggest": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/upgrade_status": "^3.11",
        "drupal/vertical_tabs_config": "^1.3",
        "drupal/viewfield": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/views_autocomplete_filters": "^1.3",
        "drupal/views_bulk_edit": "^2.4",
        "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^3.9",
        "drupal/views_conditional": "^1.3",
        "drupal/views_natural_sort": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/views_taxonomy_term_name_into_id": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/watchdog_prune": "^2.1",
        "psr/log": "^1.1",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^4.0",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^9"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the devel module that prevents you from installing. As this line indicates, it requires a version of `symfony/var-dumper` that is not compatible with Drupal 9:

```
drupal/devel           2.1.0    requires   symfony/var-dumper (~2.7|^3|^4)
```

If you change devel to the current version, e.g. `^4.1` then it should install.

Comment: Working fine, thanks for the suggestion. I've been using Drupal for over a decade, but composer has been a bit of a mystery. Now I know a little more about where to look.

Comment: Yes, composer, and especially it's errors, can be challenging and frustrating. I know that too ;)